# Is there a Whitney's approximation theorem for applications of pairs?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

In order to show that relative de Rham cohomology is a topological invariant, an equivalent of whitney's approximation theorem is needed for applications $f \colon (M,P) \to (N,Q)$ (i.e. $f(P) \subset Q$), where $M$, $N$ are smooth manifolds, $P \subset M$ a closed submanifold, and $Q \subset N$ a closed submanifold.

Do we have :

1) any continuous $f \colon (M,P) \to (N,Q)$ is (continuously) homotopic to a smooth $\tilde{f} \colon (M,P) \to (N,Q)$

2) if $f,\,g \colon (M,P) \to (N,Q)$ are smooth and (continuously) homotopic, they are smoothly homotopic.

I think it is true, but can't find any reference.

Same question for the proper version of the theorem. Do we have :

1) A proper continuous $f \colon (M,P) \to (N,Q)$ is (continuously) properly homotopic to a smooth proper $\tilde{f} \colon (M,P) \to (N,Q)$

2) if $f,\,g \colon (M,P) \to (N,Q)$ are smooth proper and (continuously) properly homotopic, they are smoothly and properly homotopic.

Comment: I think this is all in Hirsch, Differential Topology, but I will have to check to be sure.

Comment: @Ben, thx. What I have found in Hirsch is thm 3.5 p.57 saying that smooth pair maps are dense in continuous pair maps with the strong topology. Since closed enough maps are homotopic (correct ?), I think that could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good source is:

- MR0674117  Reviewed Bröcker, Theodor; Jänich, Klaus Introduction to differential topology. Translated from the German by C. B. Thomas and M. J. Thomas. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge-New York, 1982. vii+160 pp.

They do this in detail. The relative situation is only dealt with for manifolds with boundary there, but the proofs can easily be adapted:
Choose a Riemannian metric on $N$ such that $Q$ is a totally geodesic submanifold and use the exponential mapping of this metric 
in the relevant proofs.

Comment: well, I browsed through the whole Brocker's book, but couldn't find the version of Whitney approx. theorem for maps of pairs of manifolds I am looking for. I only found the relative version of Whitney's thm (thm 14.8 p150). But I think that it should be possible to prove this version for pairs using the Whitney's thm relative to $P$, the existence of open tubular neighborough of $P$ in $M$ and of $Q$ in $N$, and that C^0-close maps are homotopic.